# Hibernate insert error: ids for this class must be manually assigned before calling save():

Tags: java, hibernate

I have this problem that i can't solve, this is my entity class:

/** 
 *        @hibernate.class
 *              table="users.network_topic"
 *        @hibernate.cache usage="read-write"
*/
public class NetworkTopic implements Serializable, Idable{

```
/** identifier field */
private Long id;

/** persistent field */
private Long networkId;

/** persistent field */
private Long topicId;

private UserTopic topic;
private Network network;

/** 
 *            @hibernate.id
 *             generator-class="assigned"
 *             type="java.lang.Long"
 *             column="id"
 */
public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

/** 
 *            @hibernate.property
 *             type="java.lang.Long"
 *             column="network_id"
 *             not-null="true"
 */
public Long getNetworkId() {
    return networkId;
}

public void setNetworkId(Long networkId) {
    this.networkId = networkId;
}

/** 
 *            @hibernate.property
 *             type="java.lang.Long"
 *             column="user_topic_id"
 *             not-null="true"
 */
public Long getTopicId() {
    return topicId;
}

public void setTopicId(Long topicId) {
    this.topicId = topicId;
}   

/** 
 *            @hibernate.set
 *             lazy="true"
 *             inverse="true"
 *             cascade="none"
 *            @hibernate.key
 *             column="user_topic_id"
 *            @hibernate.one-to-many
 *             class="com.netblue.matchpoint.domain.UserTopic"
 *         
 */
public UserTopic getTopic() {
    return topic;
}

public void setTopic(UserTopic topic) {
    this.topic = topic;
}   

/** 
 *            @hibernate.set
 *             lazy="true"
 *             inverse="true"
 *             cascade="none"
 *            @hibernate.key
 *             column="network_id"
 *            @hibernate.one-to-many
 *             class="com.netblue.matchpoint.domain.Network"
 *         
 */    
public Network getNetwork() {
    return network;
}

public void setNetwork(Network network) {
    this.network = network;
}   

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Network[id=" + id + "]";
}
```

}

Then i try to save a new register with this code:

```
        UserTopic topic = new UserTopic();
        topic.setId(topicId);
        topic.setName(ParseUtil.getString(map.get(MPConstants.TOPIC_NAME_PARAM)));
        topic.setCreatedBy(ParseUtil.getInt(map.get(MPConstants.USER_ID)));
        Date now = new Date();
        topic.setCreatedDt(now);
        topic.setLastUpdatedDt(now);
        topic.setStatusId(Status.ACTIVE);
        topic.setActivityCnt(0);
        userTopicDao.saveOrUpdate(topic);

        UserTopicMap utm = new UserTopicMap();
        utm.setId(topicId);
        utm.setMtid(topicId);
        utm.setOtid(topicId);
        utm.setIsDeleted(false);
        utm.setLastUpdatedDt(now);
        userTopicMapDao.saveOrUpdate(utm);

        Network network = MpAuctionUtil.getNetworkById(networkId);
        NetworkTopic networkTopic = new NetworkTopic();
        networkTopic.setNetworkId(networkId);
        networkTopic.setTopicId(topicId);
        networkTopic.setNetwork(network);
        networkTopic.setTopic(topic);
        LOG.debug("userTopicService addObjSubscriber x networkId="+networkId+", topicId="+topicId);
        networkTopicDao.saveOrUpdate(networkTopic);
```

The last lines are the ones that fail, if i remove them it works, i mean it saves topics ok, but when i try to do this it fail, i don't know if i'm doing something wrong, please help me !!

Answer (score 0):

The NetworkTopic class hasnt been assigned an id. you must use the setId method or consider consider one of the other id strategies

[2.2.3.1. Generating the identifier property](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/annotations/3.5/reference/en/html_single/)

Comment: The database is configured to generate the ID automatically, and i thought the annotation generator-class="assigned" takes charge of this...

Comment: `assigned` would mean that the class is expecting you to assign the id manually. Based on what you are using in your database to generate the id, you might to consider between `auto`, `identity` and `sequence` strategies.

Answer (score 0):

```
NetworkTopic networkTopic = new NetworkTopic();
    networkTopic.setNetworkId(networkId);
    networkTopic.setTopicId(topicId);
    networkTopic.setNetwork(network);
    networkTopic.setTopic(topic);
    LOG.debug("userTopicService addObjSubscriber x networkId="+networkId+", topicId="+topicId);
    networkTopicDao.saveOrUpdate(networkTopic);
```

Here，you must call the method `setId`, and set the value manually, because your id generator is "assigned", and that means you must assigned manually every time before you insert or update your data!